# How to deploy the EAR application in Websphere Cluster environment using hudson or jenkins Websphere deploy plugin

Tags: java, hudson, websphere, jenkins

My requirement is to deploy the EAR application in Websphere Cluster environment using jenkin's Websphere deploy plugin.

so where to i need to specify the details like server or cell or node or cluster .

I know we use an WAS61Adapter.properties file in hudson websphere-plugin [http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Deploy+WebSphere+Plugin] version 1.0 , Do we need to mention in this property file [WAS61Adapter.properties] . If yes , what are the details ?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI. The current plugin does not support deployment if security is turned on. Most of the environment using clustered environment(s) atleast have the administrative security turned off while eliminates this  plugin as an option.

Answer (score 2):

I created a new jenkins plugin which may fit your needs.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebSphere+Deployer+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Websphere ant

check this http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fpublic_html%2Fapi%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fant%2Ftasks%2Fpackage-summary.html